# Not enough resources available

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I have setup a private cloud to get service from VM instances, but I can't run the instances:

```
cloud@node:~$ cd /home/cloud/.euca
cloud@node:~/.euca$ . eucarc

cloud@node:~/.euca$ euca-describe-availability-zones verbose
AVAILABILITYZONE cluster1 10.1.1.222
AVAILABILITYZONE |- vm types free / max cpu ram disk
AVAILABILITYZONE |- m1.small 0002 / 0002 1 192 2
AVAILABILITYZONE |- c1.medium 0002 / 0002 1 256 5
AVAILABILITYZONE |- m1.large 0001 / 0001 2 512 10
AVAILABILITYZONE |- m1.xlarge 0001 / 0001 2 1024 20
AVAILABILITYZONE |- c1.xlarge 0000 / 0000 4 2048 20

cloud@node:~/.euca$ euca-describe-images
IMAGE eki-6E341ABC lucid-20110421182259/lucid-server-uec-i386-vmlinuz-virtual.manifest.xml admin available public i386 kernel
IMAGE emi-210F15BA lucid-20110421182259/lucid-server-uec-i386.img.manifest.xml admin available public i386 machine eki-6E341ABC

cloud@node:~/.euca$ euca-run-instances emi-210F15BA -k mykey -t m1.large
FinishedVerify: Not enough resources available: addresses (try --addressing private)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message is telling your problem:

```
FinishedVerify: Not enough resources available: addresses (try --addressing private)
```

Please post the output of

```
$ euca-describe-addresses
```

Also try

```
$ euca-allocate-address
```